# Radius of convergence of power series of sub-stochastic matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, markov-chains, random-walk

Suppose I have a connected graph $G = (V,E)$, and a subset of vertices $U$, such that $W$ is the subgraph of $G$ induced by the vertices $V \setminus U$, and that $W$ is also connected.

Now, let $X_n$ be a random walk on $G$ and let $P$ be it's transition probability matrix. Now, let $Q$ be the submatrix of $P$ that corresponds to the vertices $W$. So, $Q$ is a sub-stochastic matrix (i.e. at least $1$ row sums to less than $1$)

I have shown that, for any $i,j \in W$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (Q^n)_{ij} = \mathscr{G}_U(i,j) < \infty$, and I have also shown that the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(Q^n)_{ij}$ converges for some $x > 1$, by showing that all eigenvalues of $Q$ are strictly less than $1$.

Now, I want to show that the radius of convergence, $R$, of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(Q^n)_{ij}$ does not depend on $i$ or $j$.

I am stuck here, and not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're summing over $n$, not $i$.

Assuming that, from diagonalization you have that $(Q^n)_{ij}$ is some linear combination of $\lambda_k^n$ where $\lambda_k$ are all the eigenvalues of $Q$ (say sorted in decreasing order of magnitude). So the radius of convergence is presumably $1/|\lambda_1|$, except for the possibility that somehow $(Q^n)_{ij}$ had no contribution from $\lambda_1$. But the Perron-Frobenius theorem (for general nonnegative matrices, not just stochastic matrices) forbids that, because the eigenvector $v_1$ will have everywhere nonzero entries.

Comment: Yes, summing over $n$, sorry! Also, why are we guaranteed that $Q$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: @jackson5 If it isn't, you can still write down the Jordan normal form version of this statement, but there might be some $n^\ell$'s floating around for the generalized eigenvectors. But $v_1$ will still have everywhere positive entries, so that contribution should determine the radius of convergence. However I see a snag in the periodic case: in this situation you need to be worried that the radius of convergence might go up due to cancellations between terms whose eigenvalues have the same magnitude as $\lambda_1$. In the aperiodic case what I said goes through, however.